# JDK Limit on Entity Expansions

Tags: java, jaxp

I got this error message during the transform of a large XML document:

> JAXP00010001: The parser has encountered more than "64000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the JDK.

Googled and learned about [limits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/limits.html). Then learned found how to [implement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/properties/usingProps.html) limits other than the 64K default: In may case, I needed to make a `${java.home}/lib/jaxp.properties` file<sup>1</sup> with this entry:

```
jdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit=256000
```

That worked, and is described here for others who encounter the same error.

**QUESTION**:  Does increasing expansion limits signifigantly increase security risk?

I'm guessing this limit was meant more for servers. My workstation only does net surfing.

Footnote 1: I needed to create a new jaxp.properties in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib`

Answer (score 3):

It increases the risk of a Denial of Service.  i.e. malicious XML designed solely to use up your memory, the prominent example being the [billion laughs attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs_attack).