# How can I make DITA catalog.xml work in VS Code?

Tags: xml, dita

I am using VS Code and the "XML Language Support by Red Hat". I am pointing to the catalog file inside the DITA OT directory `dita-ot-3.3.3\catalog-dita.xml`. My DITA file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE task PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Task//EN" "http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.1/OS/dtd/task.dtd">
<task>
    <title>Running the converter</title>
    <steps>
        <step>
            <cmd>Run the following command:</cmd>
        </step>
    </steps>
</task>
```

But I get errors like:

```
Element type "task" must be declared.xml(MSG_ELEMENT_NOT_DECLARED)
```

So it's reading something, but it's not working correctly. Am I using the wrong catalog file? Is my document declaration wrong?

An aside: I have Oxygen XML Editor and I can use that if I need advanced functions. I am looking to use VS Code for occasional small edits while I'm coding without having to launch Oxygen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit `settings.json` to validate against DTD using catalog file as follows:

[image: Editing setting.json]

You must set "`xml.catalogs`","`xml.javahome`", "`xml.validation.resolveExternalEntities`" respectively.

Then you can get the succeeded validation result:

[image: Validation result]

By the way, your DITA file is originally not valid against DITA DTD.

Comment: This perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Toshihiko san's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64788422/5360420) is spot on, thanks for that! But I found that in 2023, with DITA 4.0.2 at least, I wasn't able to use Intellisense code completion in any topic type because of the following error on the root element:

```
The parser has encountered more than "64,000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the application.
```

[image]

To fix this, I needed to increase the entity expansion limit¹ as an added JVM option in the VS Code settings (just doubling 64000 seemed to do the trick):

```
"xml.server.vmargs": "-Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit=128000"
```

For completeness, here are all the entries I needed for the Red Hat XML VS Code extension to work with DITA (that I know of so far):

[image]

---

¹ Note as to [why the 64,000 entity limit was imposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809558/jdk-limit-on-entity-expansions/46292474#46292474).

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, @arkadianriver. This really helped me